# How to ensure JSON object structure using type and interface in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a couple of modules and components in my angular project. I have created a router config file for easy handling of routing and it contains JSON data as follows.

router.config.ts

```
 {
   branch:{
     list:'/app/branch/list',
     add:'/app/branch/add'
   },
   books:{
      publish:'/app/books/publish',
      manage:'/app/books/manage'
   }
 }
```

So based on configuration, the routing would be easy.

```
<a routerLink="branch.list">
  Branch list
</a>

<a routerLink="books.publish">
  Publish book
</a>
```

I want to validate the router config objects. How do I validate that by using `interface` and `type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface Route {
    [key: string]:
    { [key: string]: string }
}

const Routes :Route[] = [
{
    branch:{
      list:'/app/branch/list',
      add:'/app/branch/add'
    },
    books:{
       publish:'/app/books/publish',
       manage:'/app/books/manage'
    }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

define router Item like this:

```
interface RouterItem {
  list: string;
  add: string;
}
```

and this function for instance validation:

```
function isInstanceOfRouterItem(obj: any){
  return 'list' in obj && 'add' in obj;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the keys won't be the same. I have edited the question.